# page load on validate user

Tags: c#, asp.net, pageload, autologin

I want to ask how to load page using validate user using Request String.
I have code below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string ValidateUser = Request.QueryString["inisial"];
    if (ValidateUser != null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    }
    string x = Request.QueryString["ind"];
    if (ValidateUser != null)
    {
      Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
    }
}
protected void ValidateUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int userId = 0;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConn"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Validate_User"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Request.QueryString["inisial"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Request.QueryString["ind"]);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();
        }
        switch (userId)
        {
            case -1:
                Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                break;
            case -2:
                Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated.";
                break;
            default:
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to login system using request string to change username and password with url:

```
http://default.aspx?id_sistem=24&inisial=gdm&ind=7/17/2004 4:50:40 PM
```

example :
username = (gdm), password = (7/17/2004 4:50:40)

Please Correct Me If I'm Wrong
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you should use a query string in your URL for the username and password, I suggest creating a method where the user is authenticated and then set a session variable that stores a bool whether the user is authenticated or not.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Authenticated"] != null)
        {
            bool authenticated = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["Authenticated"]);
            if (!authenticated)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
            }

        }
     }
```